# Looping through a raster brick

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I know there are a large number of questions on here about looping through raster bricks, but none of them provide quite the answer/advice I'm looking for.

I have a large (17.2GB, 7901 layers) `netcdf` file that I've imported into `R` as a `RasterBrick`.

```
> KK10Brick
class       : RasterBrick 
dimensions  : 2160, 4320, 9331200, 7901  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 0.08333333, 0.08333333  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : D:\LandUse\KK10.nc 
names       : X8000, X7999, X7998, X7997, X7996, X7995, X7994, X7993, X7992, X7991, X7990, X7989, X7988, X7987, X7986, ... 
z-value     : 100, 8000 (min, max)
varname     : land_use
```

Each layer in the file represents 1 year and I need to create a temporal moving average of each pixel in the brick. Even though the variable seems categorical (`land_use`) it is actually a % cover.

I want to create a 30 year moving average, with a 10 year sliding window. e.g. the first window would produce a raster of the average values from layers `1:30`, the next window produces another raster of the average values from layers `11:40`...`7871:7901`.

I was thinking a for loop would probably be the best way to accomplish this, but I'm not sure if I'm headed down the right path here e.g.

```
for (i in 1:7901){
subsetLayers <- code to subset relevant layers
out <- stackApply(KK10Brick, indices = subsetLayers, fun = "mean", na.rm = TRUE, filename = paste("./Output/", "meanLU_window_", i, ".tif", sep = ""))
rm(out)}
```

Where I'm stuck is writing the code to produce the sequences for `subsetLayers`. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

EDIT.

```
library(raster)
exBrick <- brick(nrow = 180, ncol = 360, nl = 100)
values(exBrick) <- runif(ncell(exBrick) * nlayers(exBrick))
crs(exBrick) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0" 
exBrick
```

Comment: @dww I've added in some code for a sample raster brick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work on your example data. I'm not sure how well it will scale to your very large netcdf data in terms of speed and RAM usage - please let me know if it works on large data.

```
starts = seq(1, nlayers(exBrick)-30, 10)
nout = length(starts)
out = brick(nrow = 180, ncol = 360, nl = nout)
values(out) = NA
crs(out) = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0" 

for (i in 1:nout) {
  start = starts[i]
  out[[i]] = mean(exBrick[[start:(start+30)]]) 
}
```

In case RAM usage is the limiting factor from allocating a large brick to store the results, we can save RAM at the cost of some speed by saving each result layer to disk, one raster at a time:

```
for (i in starts) {
  out = mean(exBrick[[i:(i+30)]]) 
  writeRaster(out, filename=paste0("out",i,".grd"), overwrite=TRUE)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Allocating NA values to a raster with the same number of rows/columns/layers as my real dataset requires 27.5GB RAM. I've got access to machines with ~200GB RAM so I'll let you know how it goes in the next few days.

Comment: @KaanKaant the raster brick I allocate for the results has only one tenth the layers of the original data. So should only be less than 3GB. I've also added an edit that also shows how to reduce ram usage by saving results one layer at a time.